# htaccess - how to redirect when 403 and 404 based on the DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

1. I have an application in PHP running on Apache (Linux).

   2. When the client is local (LAN), DOCUMENT_ROOT is: /webroot/public_html/app
   3. When the client is remote (WAN), DOCUMENT_ROOT is: /webroot/public_html/extapp
   4. I would like the .htaccess file, when an 403 or 404 occurs, Apache could redirect, something similar:

ErrorDocument 403 ( DOCUMENT_ROOT === '/app' ) ? /app/error/403.php : /extapp/error/403.php

Thanks!

Comment: not possible. errordoc directives do a SIMPLE mapping of http code -> single script. if you want to load different files, then `ErrorDocument 403 somescript.php`, and put logic into that ONE script to load the appropriate data: `<?php if ($is_lan) { load_lan(); } else { load_wan(); }`

Comment: Thanks! I really thought I could something like that, because there is an instruction RewriteEngine On, that turn on the rewriting engine and allows to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: errordocument has NOTHING to do with mod_rewrite. that's like saying. "I thought eating this banana would teach me how to drive that ferrari"